# how to display a a tabbar on a page without calling it in appdelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tabbarcontroller

I want to display `tabbar` with `tabbaritems` on a page. But the main problem is that I don't want the the `tabbarcontroller` to be called from delegate class. So how is this possible. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your .h file

IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabbarcontroller;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITabBarController *tabbarcontroller;

in your .m file

```
[self.view addSubview:tabbarcontroller.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

You just create and add a `UITabBar` as a subview of your chosen view. You don't need a `UITabBarController` to have a tabbar, and even if you do you can add that view to an existing view controller, rather than having it in your delegate.

Comment: How to make uitabbar as subview of my chosen view